# CouchDB - Get custom fields within _users for replication filtering

Tags: couchdb

I am developing a simple client for Android which fetches data from a CouchDB database. There will be only one database for all users. The data pull-replicated is filtered by a JS function. Such function (simplified) would be like this:

```
function(doc,req) {
    if (!doc.type || doc.type !='item') { return false; }
    if (doc.foo && ... && req.userCtx.bar.indexOf(doc.foo) != -1) { return true; }
    ...
}
```

As I have read in the [official documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/security.html#users-documents), `_users` is a perfect place to set custom fields related to the user. So did I as you can see in the above code (see `req.userCtx.bar` array).

The problem I am facing is that the object/JSON `req.userCtx` [only contains](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/json-structure.html?highlight=user#user-context-object)  these fields: `db`, `name` and `roles`.

**1.** What would be a good alternative to my idea? I am a little bit stuck right now at this point. **2.** How can I retrieve the user's data (all fields official and custom)?. **3.** Is it correct to add as filter parameter a large array?

**NOTE**

I am thinking of a messy alternative of adding an array-field in every `item` which will contain the list with all users allowed to pull such `item` although I have the feeling that there must be another way.

Answer (score 1):

Saving user data in `_users` is interesting because only the user or an admin can read a user's document.

However, as you've found out, that doesn't mean that all user data is available to the `userCtx` object. All you get is the user's `name` and `roles` array. Can you make do with `roles`?

To retrieve all of the user's data, you should fetch the user's document from the `_users` database. You can do that with a `GET` request on `http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:[USER]`.

To know what would be an appropriate solution to your problem, we'd need quite a bit more info. For instance, looking at your code, it seems you designed that filter with the intention of restricting replication to documents listed as being visible to the user. However, you can't really lock down CouchDB in a way that replication works, and the user doesn't have read access to the entire database. You really need one db per user for this to work.

Comment: Is it possible to set it in name field instead? I think we can override validator doc to not check name field and let it store all json data but I don't know what limitation of name field